# CSS formatting not applied to window.print()

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am generating an HTML table with Javascript and displaying it in a new window.  After generating the window, I want to open a print window so the user can save it to a PDF.  However, when the print window appears, the formatting is lost.  If, instead, I just right click on the table window and choose print, then the formatting in the print window is correct.  I have applied @media print, screen {...} to all of my CSS items.

```
...
@media print, screen {
  /* CSS Items */
}
...

...
myWindow.focus();
myWindow.print();
...
```

Comment: are you adding the css to the new window or just including it in the main window/tab? If the latter you will need to actually include the css into the new window for it to be used

Comment: Thanks you @PatrickEvans - When I write to the new window I include the CSS file: myWindow.document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='popup_style.css'> ").  The formatting is then correct in the new window - and correct when I right click to print, but incorrect if I issue myWindow.print().

Comment: Sounds like a bug. See if it's reported on https://crbug.com or report it yourself.